# Is it possible to filter data based on its plot/predicted curve?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, glm, loess

I had a question regarding excluding/filtering data points. I currently have coded a logistic regression that generates a decision boundary that is wrapped up into a function in which I am able to run over subsets of my data frame.

I was wondering, if I were to plot all of the predicted curves based on these outcomes, if it is possible to filter these decision boundaries even further based on their generated plot/curve. Or if it is possible to set requirements in order for a curve to “qualify” and track the corresponding data in the data frame...

```
## glm that generates a midpoint/decision boundary, wrapped into a function

get_midpoint = function(data){
      glm.1 = glm(coderesponse~stimulus, family = binomial(link="logit"), data=data, na.action = na.exclude)
      rtn = -glm.1$coefficients[1]/glm.1$coefficients[2]
rtn
}

## a mini dummy dataframe 

subject <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)
stimulus = c(1, 5, 50, 35, 23, 2, 4, 22, 15, 6, 20, 40, 45, 10, 37, 43, 48, 7, 19, 21, 29, 49, 26, 11, 36, 30, 39, 41, 16, 37, 1, 5, 50, 35, 23, 2, 4, 22, 15, 6, 20, 40, 45, 10, 37, 43, 48, 7, 19, 21, 29, 49, 26, 11, 36, 30, 39, 41, 16, 37)
stim <- c('bd', 'nd', 'nm', 'bd', 'nd', 'nm', 'bd', 'nd', 'nm', 'bd', 'nd', 'nm', 'bd', 'nd', 'nm', 'bd', 'nd', 'nm', 'bd', 'nd', 'nm', 'bd', 'nd', 'nm', 'bd', 'nd', 'nm', 'bd', 'nd', 'nm', 'bd', 'nd', 'nm', 'bd', 'nd', 'nm', 'bd', 'nd', 'nm', 'bd', 'nd', 'nm', 'bd', 'nd', 'nm', 'bd', 'nd', 'nm', 'bd', 'nd', 'nm', 'bd', 'nd', 'nm', 'bd', 'nd', 'nm', 'bd', 'nd', 'nm')
block <- c('mouth', 'mouth', 'mouth', 'nose', 'nose', 'nose', 'mouth', 'mouth', 'mouth', 'nose', 'nose', 'nose', 'mouth', 'mouth', 'mouth', 'nose', 'nose', 'nose', 'mouth', 'mouth', 'mouth', 'nose', 'nose', 'nose', 'mouth', 'mouth', 'mouth', 'nose', 'nose', 'nose', 'mouth', 'mouth', 'mouth', 'nose', 'nose', 'nose', 'mouth', 'mouth', 'mouth', 'nose', 'nose', 'nose', 'mouth', 'mouth', 'mouth', 'nose', 'nose', 'nose', 'mouth', 'mouth', 'mouth', 'nose', 'nose', 'nose', 'mouth', 'mouth', 'mouth', 'nose', 'nose', 'nose')
coderesponse <- c(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0)

df = data.frame(subject, stimulus, stim, block, coderesponse)

## running the function over defined subgroups of ~80 rows each [for the real data]
## but for the dummy dataframe, only ~5 rows

df = df %>% 
  nest(data=-c(subject, stim, block)) %>%
  mutate(midpoint=map_dbl(data, get_midpoint)) %>%
  unnest()

## basic code that plots and creates a curve based on a single glm result
## QUESTION: want to be able to run this over the same subgroups as above to create curves for every midpoint generated and then possibly filter based on the curve?
plot(df$stimulus,df$coderesponse,xlab="stimulus",ylab="Probability of d responses")
curve(predict(glm.1,data.frame(stimulus=x),type="response"),add=TRUE)
```

I’m quite new and confused with this part of R, so thanks for any help or insight!

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. It's a bit unclear what you are describing.

Comment: Edited! Hope it clarifies things.

Comment: When running this, I get a `object 'glm.1' not found` error in the last line. I see the model embedded in the `get_midpoint()` fx used in your `mutate`, but you don't return the `glm.1` model anywhere.

Comment: @Steven ah sorry, The last piece of code (e.g. lines regarding `plot` & `curve` prediction) is only applicable to a single output from the `glm.1` model. I'm trying to figure out how to modify it to output the plot and curves in correspondence to values generated from the `get_midpoint()` function, which I'm still having trouble with. 

edit: Is it possible to plot all of the glm.1 values from the subgroups of data using ggplot or does it require some sort of function?

Comment: @LizJu I'm still unsure if I understand exactly what you're looking for. It reads to me like you want to model `coderesponse~stimulus` as a `glm`, grouped by `subject`, then plot the data and each model on the same figure. If that's the case, easy. `ggplot()` can plot models for you. If it's something else, I'm missing a key component for my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying to do is the following:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  ggplot() +
  aes(x = stimulus, y = coderesponse, colour = subject %>% as.factor()) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = 'glm', method.args = list(family = binomial(link='logit')), se = F) +
  scale_colour_discrete(name = "Subject") +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

This takes your original `df` and simply plots the data, colored by `subject`, then runs the `glm` model over both `subject` groups in your data. You can run each `glm` outside of the `geom_smooth()` statement if you need to use them to predict. There could be a way to use the `ggplot`-produced models without burning additional computations on remodeling.